# Drupal 8.2.6 /tmp

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, file-permissions, drupal-8, tmp

```
Drupal 8.2.6
Media Entity 8.x-1.0-alpha4
Ctools 8.x-3.0-alpha27
```

So after turn on CSS/JS aggregation I noticed that I can not upload images anymore. When I try to upload an image it gave me an error. So I changed my tmp directory to

```
sites/default/files/tmp
```

but that didn't help and gave me an error of

```
The file could not be saved. An unknown error has occurred.
File upload error. Could not move uploaded file.
This value should not be null.
```

I checked the permissions. default folder is 755. files folder is 755. tmp folder is 755. This also started affecting my Drupal 7 website after I enabled aggregation, so I am certain this is what is affecting my site.

Any information or leads would be very helpful, as I've been stuck.

Comment: did you check user who is owner ? www-data must be owner , he need to create some directories pour generate css aggregated files

Comment: Which folder do I check for ownership? All of the files are owned by the same owner. I did check error message and get this message:

Upload error. Could not move uploaded file x.png to destination private://2017-03/x.png.

Comment: private:// <= files_private , www-data must be owner of tmp , files and files_private .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long 2 days struggling to find the answer, I finally found a temporary solution. I used the command `chmod -R 1777 /tmp` . Then in admin/config/media/file-system I set directory to /tmp . Might have security vulnerabilities, but it works for me.